# How to set (scrollable) UITextView's height based on UIView's height

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have UITextView like this, :

[image]

I want to keep 'padding-top' and 'padding-bottom' = 20pts. I'm using this 'padding' term because I'm usually doing CSS.

since I created that storyboard under 4 inch configuration, padding-bottom will be gone when it runs on 3.5 inch display.

so I decided to measure height of UIView first by having this code :

```
CGFloat screenHeight = _screen.frame.size.height;
float scrollHeight = screenHeight - 40;
```

scrollHeight is height of UITextView that I expect. it's dynamically calculated based on display size so I hope I still can see padding-bottom on 3.5 inch.

I tried this code to set UITextView's height, but failed :

```
_textViewTerms.frame = CGRectInset(_textViewTerms.frame,0,20);
```

here's my interface :

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *screen;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textViewTerms;
```

Comment: What do you get if you NSLog `_textViewTerms.frame` before `_textViewTerms.frame = CGRectInset(_textViewTerms.frame,0,20);`? It might not be set yet.

Comment: never mind... I already solve this problem... thanks for remind me about NSLog.